# Dynamic SQL on mySQL 8

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

The plan is to construct a dynamic sql that will execute create view statements. We have multiple servers but the schemas are the same across all servers.

I have started off with the following,

```
set @businessId = 'buName-1234.';
SET @table_name:= concat(@businessId,'Test');
SELECT @table_name;
SET @sql:=CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ',@table_name);
SELECT @sql;
```

which gives the output as,

```
SELECT * FROM buName-1234.Test
```

The issue arises on the execution part,

```
PREPARE dynamic_statement FROM @sql;
EXECUTE dynamic_statement;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE dynamic_statement;
```

The error is,

*Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near **'-1234.Test'** at line 1*

I have tried changing the single quote `set @businessId = 'buName-1234.';` to a backtick, but that also fails with error,

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'buName-1234.' in 'field list'
```

The error can't be replicated on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ce0d6a51f3e2be179565bae1a6115037)

Comment: Ok first of all I notice that in dbfiddle.uk, there are some error that it won't show or maybe since the query isn't valid, it doesn't continue to the next statement. You might want to try [another fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5wy4Ah9AUnC4AjYDBozbQM/0). Second thing is, you need to always use backticks for database or tables or columns that contain punctuation marks (as what you already discovered yourself). I honestly think its better to use underscore ( `_` ) though. I'm aware that some people don't have control over the naming but if you do, I suggest you change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenating backticks to the server name is the way to do this in my case, like so,

```
SET @databaseName= 'buName-1234';
SET @table = 'Test';
SET @fullTable_name:= concat("`",@databaseName,"`.",@table);
SET @sql:= CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ',@fullTable_name,";");
SELECT @sql
```

which give the output as,

```
 SELECT * FROM `buName-1234`.Test;
```

which can be used in PREPARE & EXECUTE.